# Is there any way to show child theme in theme detectors?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I am using a child theme of Colormag on my WordPress site (I am a developer).

I named my theme "happiness" but whenever I check theme using an external theme detector, say "[WP Detector](http://www.wpthemedetector.com/)", it shows that my site is using Colormag.

I hope I'll get some help here, cheers!

**UPDATE**

My child theme is completely functioning, you can check it yourself: [my site](http://www.baatega.com)

**SOLVED**

I don't know why but one of my style-sheet was referenced to parent theme. I copied that to my child theme and problem is now solved. Good Luck if someone gets to the same problem.

Comment: I suspect that all this theme detector does is look in the HTML for the path to your CSS. If you are pulling in the parent theme CSS then the detector may assume that that is your theme. If your own template files are loading ok and your own stylesheet is being used then your child theme is working.

Comment: If someone downvotes a question, the reason should be a common knowledge.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, so the system marks this question ad solved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but one of my style-sheet was referenced to parent theme. I copied that to my child theme and problem is now solved. Good Luck if someone gets to the same problem.

To be more specific if you ever encounter this issue, just check you css files. Modern Theme checkers simply look for `@import` and will find parent theme from your directory.

Answer (score 0):

some rules you need to follow when creating a child theme are:

1. A child theme consists of at least one directory (the child theme directory) and two files (style.css and functions.php), which you will need to create:

The child theme directory
style.css
functions.php

2. It is recommended (though not required, especially if you're creating a theme for public use) that the name of your child theme directory is appended with '-child'.
3. The next step is to create your child theme's stylesheet (style.css). The stylesheet must begin with the following (the stylesheet header):

   /*Theme Name:   Happiness 
     *Template:     colormag
   */

"Template" should be your parent template name.

Comment: I know this, did not I told that my child theme is completely functioning?

Comment: you have just now updated your question. This was before the update :)